# Is "bridles lashing about the horses" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Not sure what preposition + verb combinations you can use with bridles and horses. Is there a way of figuring these out as a non-native speaker? I feel you can only know after memorizing a couple of examples.

Anyway, the real question is the following:

Is the following grammatically correct?

> **The bridles were lashing about the horses** as the horsemen were trying to escape the King's cavalry.

I am not sure why, but there's something about this sentence that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Bridles* are the headgear placed on horses' heads in order to keep them controlled:

[image: bridle]

It wouldn't make any sense to say that this headgear was *lashing about the horses*. If it were loose in that way, it would be a serious problem.

---

Instead, the word you're looking for is most likely [**reins**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rein):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : a strap fastened to a bit by which a rider or driver controls an animal —usually used in plural

In the picture, the reins are the straps that have been fastened *to* the horse's bridle, through a ring that's also connected to the bit in its mouth.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know where you found your original sentence, but the way you mention **prepositions** and verbs makes me wonder if you’re analyzing it correctly.

It’s not:

> **The bridles were lashing** [about the horses]...

where *about* is a preposition; rather, *about* is an adverb, describing how the bridles were lashing.

Consider this definition from Wordnik:

> **about** (*adv.*) All around; on every side: *Let's look about for help*.

So, your sentence could be rephrased as:

> The bridles were lashing **all around the horses** as the horsemen were trying to escape the King's cavalry.

One way we can tell that *about* is an adverb here is that we can omit the phrase “the horses” and the sentence still makes sense:

> The bridles were lashing about as the horsemen were trying to escape the King's cavalry.

I’m not going to address the difference between *bridles* and *reins* as that was already discussed in another answer.

Comment: I thought it was an adverb meaning:  On all sides of